# SP version history is different from version history dispayed in Office application

Tags: 2010, versioning, content-deployment, version-history

Have you any idea why office application like Excel or Word shows different name in version history than SP version history? This is version history of some Excel file viewed through SP GUI:

[image]

... and the same file viewed through MS Excel app.

[image]

From where is the atribute comes from or what Excel read after my file was open? And to make it even harder, **what should I do, if the files was digitally signed** and MS Word displays warning message that the integrity of this file was broken and its untrusted now because of different names?

Affected files was deployed through CD job and their versions through PowerShell script under system account (or Kamil's, used on image above). In fact, all moved versions of all Office documents change their ownership, but we need to solve this situation mainly for the digitally signed ones.

... beside that, how can we move document versions after CD jobs in right way? PS damage ownership, moving one by one is not a solution, for example this affected place contains thousand of files, migration tool is not the solution, because it cause all problems, that we have now.

Comment: First look who Kamil is, what they had to do with the document, follow baby steps in that respect. Did they upload the document, where they the creators? Are they the system administrator account that some script somewhere raises permissions too? Finding out who Kamil is to that file will give you the answer.

Comment: I know who Kamil is, he belongs to farm admins with the highest rights and script for version moving was launched under his account. The point is somewhere else - if you move versions via standard SP commands (export/import) you will be the owner of those changes according to MS Office apps. The situation is the same, if we run it under system (or any other account with rights), only name in Office Home tab would be System, not Kamil.

Comment: It appears that something somewhere, an event receiver or a workflow is probably setting it by the logged in user name. It is the only logical reason for it, the system is picking up the logged in user name and setting it, the internal modified by for the file isn't being changed however just the file table modified by name (The two lists show from different sources of modified by) if you know the script you would have to modify it to get the internal modified by name of the document and set it in the list yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was reported to Microsoft Support few days after this thread was created and we finally found the solution - the only thing, that we need to do before CD job is launched is to disable [Property Promotion function](http://kli.dk/2011/05/24/property-promotion/). Before that, I did not know that such a function exists.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood the problem, it's seems like you're talking about the differences between author names of the document right ?

My idea may be too easy but it may help to deep further. In SP, the "modified by" name is directly linked to the SP account, but in office document, there's also a native property named "Author", and other properties that describes who is the user of Office Excel.

Are we sure Excel does not publish that property instead of the Windows/SP Account used to modify the document ?

As I said, that one may be to easy to be the right solution.. but who knows ?

Good Luck.

Romain

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because you have a workflow (perhaps you're using the Approval Workflow to publish major versions?) or event handler that has been developed/deployed by "Kamil" that does some kind of update on the document.

(We see a similr situation where we have an updatedEvent handler that modifies the permissions on a document after it has been saved by the user - the document's version history when viewed in Word 2010 shows the most recent version having been updated by System Account, but the version history viewed in SharePoint shows the update as having been by the actual user.)

Regards,
Aman