# Digitally signing a docx on sharepoint document library with no need to open the document with C#

Tags: development, digital-signature

My question is that is it possible to sign documents without the need to open that document?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, it's bad. Only user (account) paired with CA can do changes and changes are saved trhrough application (in hash code). Unfortunatelly, some atributes could be changed, I just try to solve problem with "modify by" changes in document versions after moving them through powershell [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43862/sp-version-history-is-different-from-version-history-dispayed-in-office-applicat).